# Set Property of FilterSecurityInterceptor in Java code

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to set `alwaysReauthenticate` in my `AbstractSecurityInterceptor` by using Spring like this

```
<bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="alwaysReauthenticate" value="true"/>
...
</bean>
```

But I don't want to use an XML file for this. I want to set this property in the Java code, maybe as `@Configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below JavaConfig on how to set the property and also you can [read more about Post Processing Configured Objects in the Spring Security Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#post-processing-configured-objects).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//..

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<FilterSecurityInterceptor>() {
                public <O extends FilterSecurityInterceptor> O postProcess(O fsi) {
                    fsi.setAlwaysReauthenticate(true);
                    return fsi;
                }
            }).and(); //continue from here on
}


//..

}
```

Comment: The method authenticated() is undefined for the type ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry

Comment: you are getting this at compile time or runtime?

Comment: at compile time